# How do you grab a title off of a button for Jest testing?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

I am trying to grab a title off of a LWC button that is a basic component button with a title as `title='Enabled button'`. Right now I am checking if it is disabled by doing `expect(selectBtn.disabled).toBe(false);` and this is working to check if it is disabled or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this to work do `expect(selectBtn.title).toBe('Enabled button');` as this will go ahead and select the title attribute off of the button